# Run Maven ant plugin after the .war is deployed?

Tags: maven, docker, ant, war

I'm currently trying to create a docker image based on my war file which will be created within the target folder when deployed. But the ant plugin executes the  command before the maven war file is deployed into target folder. Due to that though it try to create a docker image it won't find the necessary .war file to add since it hasn't being deployed into target folder.

The ant plugin is also declared under a separate profile called docker. Though I read about the [Maven Lifecycle Doc](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html), couldn't find a proper approach to achieve this.

**Here is my .pom file**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">


<groupId>org.ravindu</groupId>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>ravindu_test</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<name>Ravindu_Test_Proj</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>[4.0,)</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.facebook4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>facebook4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>[2.1,)</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>20.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compress</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/imported_js/**</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/jsqrcode/**</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/imported_css/**</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/imported_js/**</exclude>
                            <exclude>**/jsqrcode/**</exclude>
                            <exclude>**/css/**</exclude>
                            <exclude>**/images/**</exclude>
                            <exclude>**/jquery-mobile/**</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>ravTest</finalName>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>docker</id>
        <activation>
            <file>
                <exists>src/main/docker/Dockerfile</exists>
            </file>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>copy-resources</id>
                            <phase>validate</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target</outputDirectory>
                                <resources>
                                    <resource>
                                        <directory>src/main/docker</directory>
                                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                                    </resource>
                                </resources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>process-classes</id>
                            <phase>process-classes</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <target>
                                    <exec executable="docker">
                                        <arg value="build"/>
                                        <arg value="-t"/>
                                        <arg value="ravindu_test"/>
                                        <arg value="target"/>
                                    </exec>
                                    <!--<exec executable="docker">-->
                                        <!--<arg value="push"/>-->
                                        <!--<arg value="ravindu_test"/>-->
                                    <!--</exec>-->
                                    <!--<exec executable="docker">-->
                                        <!--<arg value="tag"/>-->
                                        <!--<arg value="-f"/>-->
                                        <!--<arg value="ravindu_test"/>-->
                                        <!--<arg value="ravindu_test"/>-->
                                    <!--</exec>-->
                                    <!--<exec executable="docker">-->
                                        <!--<arg value="push"/>-->
                                        <!--<arg value="ravindu_test:latest"/>-->
                                    <!--</exec>-->
                                </target>
                            </configuration>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

**Attached below is my Dockerfile**

```
# Pull base image
FROM tomcat:8-jre8

# Maintainer
MAINTAINER "Ravindu Fernando. <ravindu_fernando@gmail.com">

# Copy to images tomcat path
ADD /Ravindu_Test/target/mobile.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps
```

Comment: I would suggest to use https://github.com/fabric8io/docker-maven-plugin if you need docker support in your maven build...Also I would suggest to extract the docker part from the Maven build cause this is something different. So separation of concerns...Furthermore I would keep the default layouts cause you have changed the folders which I can not recommend.

Comment: Many thanks for the recommendation of the correct approach. But won't this  kind of approach would give us more control over managing docker? The reason I've gone to this approach after reffering these two resources -> [link](https://medium.com/@ladislavGazo/building-docker-java-app-images-with-maven-bdd88305abb#.dd7xse8ww) & [link](https://binfalse.de/2016/05/31/mvn-automagically-create-a-docker-image/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this issue didn't have to do anything with the maven as I first thought it would. The problem was with my Dockerfile. It's not identifying the fully qualified file name path for the war file as specified in my Dockerfile.

It worked after I have changed the fully qualified path of the .war file to /mobile.war after I went through the an official issue which has been raised in docker repo. It adds file from the root of the context

[Here is the link for that issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/4592)

Here is my updated Dockerfile

```
# Pull base image
FROM tomcat:8-jre8

# Maintainer
MAINTAINER "Ravindu Fernando. <ravindu_fernando@gmail.com">

# Copy to images tomcat path
ADD /mobile.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps
```

Many thanks for the answers and suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

I don`t have the exact answer for this question. But i try to explain our approach for solving this issue. Maven is a good tool for building standard project with identical structure and build phases. If you want get something more complex maven will resist it. Therefore we had decide a bit different approach:

- Maven is used only for building application (jar, war, etc...)
- All docker artifacts creates with bash scripts, which contains commands for building application with maven, building docker image and pushing it to repository.

I think for this purpose bash more convinient and flexible then maven

Comment: Thanks for the useful info about your approach. I absolutely get your point. I decided to go with this approach after referring some examples and blog posts. But ended up with this issue. Currently we have bash scripts which contains commands to build the application with maven. I wanted to create, tag and push docker image at once from the maven build. Should give a try and see with your approach as well.